# Issue found: Invalid Data safety section. How to fix this issue?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

[image: Issue found: Invalid Data safety section]

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

```
SPLIT_BUNDLE 14: Policy Declaration for Play Safety Label: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to fill out the form for google developer console

1. From the left hand side bar scroll down to **App contents** section and the right pane scroll down to data safety and click on manage
2. Click on next for the **Data security** page.
3. Select option as required
4. Select next and click on the arrow to start answering the questions
5. Answer all the questions as per your requirement.
6. Once all changes are done click on save and submit the changes for review

Comment: As a side note, It's a good idea to prepare the answer for the questions beforehand :)