# how to resolve Issue: Invalid Data safety form

Tags: android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

despite the fact that my app has nothing to do with users data security (a simple credit calculation app), every time I publish it on the Google Play console, I get this message:

[image: Message]

build.gradle(:app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    namespace '***************************'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***********************************e"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    //buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

**Please, tell me where do you see the user data breach, and help me
how to solve this problem. thanks to all**

Comment: This might help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298230/17985195)

Comment: That's what i do every Time, but non result

Comment: Apparently you are collecting more data than what you declared in this data safety form. Try to declare "yes" to literally everything in this data safety form and see if the issue still arises. If not, then you can re-upload but with narrower declarations. That way you can narrow down to which particular declaration is causing this problem

Comment: Here are some things you should know:
First of all the difference between the latest version and the current version of my application, is only to add some text box to display the calculation results.
Secondly, there is no user data used in my application, it is a simple calculator of the user’s ability to have a loan.
Thank you very much

Comment: There you go, so in theory those text boxes that you added has violated the safety checks. To confirm, in a separate branch remove those text boxes (basically reverted back to your working version) and see if the safety check warnings still come up. If they do not show, then the new text boxes you added definitely has violated somethings with google play

Comment: If that works out let me know, I am curious at this point too :D

Comment: @TP95 Ok I hope

Comment: @TP95 ****
I mean, it’s all right.
Just enter the following variations in the build.gradle(app) file:
`compileSdk 33
targetSdk 33
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.3.0'`
instead of: 
`compileSdk 34
targetSdk 34
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is directly related to the SDK version used:

Instead of version 34, use version 33 of the SDK (of course in the build.gradle(app) file) and of course the dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.3.0` instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0`. And that’s it.
Do not hesitate to put your solutions.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to SDK 33 will be a temporary solution. If you decide to update your app after ~September 2024 you will have to increase it to SDK 34 as it will be mandatory for updates and new apps(new apps a bit earlier).

We received the same rejection reason for our app when a target SDK 34 build was submitted. The changes around targeting SDK 34 were

- increase Gradle to 8.x
- increase AGP to 8.x
- update Google Billing Lib from 5.2.0 to 5.2.1(supports SDK 34)
- transition from ProGuard to R8
- update build system JDK from 11 to 17

No changes to how data was processed so the rejection did not make much sense. Added to that is the fact that the rejection message does not include list of offending libraries. So we decided to

- upload new build from last release with target SDK 33
- upload new build for the target SDK 34

No code changes were done. The target SDK 33 build was approved within 30-60 min. The target SDK 34 build took 2 days and was approved.

My suggestion is to try again for you and anyone who has a similar use-case. If however new libraries are introduced you should check what data is collected there from the respective documentations and go again through the Data Safety questions.